# Why my content is sliding into other screen when I change screen size to responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have placed text over the background image, but when I change the screen size the background position remains same but text gets out of background image.

I was expecting that when I change the screen size everting remains as it was with original screen.
Below is the CSS for the above component. What I want is to happen is when I change the screen size then the text over the image appear over the image only, which is here getting out of image

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap');

.Intro_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.hero {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.hero .content {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.hero .content h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding: 0.6rem 0 1.5rem;\
}

.hero .content p {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content .btn {
    margin: 1rem 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .hero .content h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .hero .content p {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }

    .Intro_image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      object-fit: fill;
    }    
}
  
.hero h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80%;
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(231, 40, 40, 0);
}
  
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
      background-position: -500%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 500%;
    }
}

#foot {
    position: absolute;
   
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 50px;
   
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #d9d4e7;
    width: 200px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #d9d4e7;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: solid;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
import "./HeroImgStyles.css";
import React from "react";
import IntroImage from "../assets/nasa.jpg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Fade from "react-reveal/Fade";

const HeroImg = () => {
  return (
    <div className="hero">
      <img className="Intro_image" src={IntroImage} />

      <div className="content">
        <Fade bottom>
          <p className="top"> PASSION. POSSIBILITIES. INNOVATIONS! </p>
        </Fade>
        <h1></h1>
        <div>
          <Link to="/projects" className="btn">
            Products
          </Link>

          <Link to="/contact" className="btn">
            Contact Us
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeroImg;
```

Comment: Can you share the code on stackBlitz or codesandbox

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make the code into a runnable snippet within your question not on an external site. The reason being, @KannuMandora is that SO is trying to build up a library of useful answers for future readers and external sites can disappear.

Comment: i fixed that was becuase of height and widht was in %